# onBeforeRequest not run every time something is clicked

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, dom-events, webrequest

**Update 1:**
Now thanks to Xan I no longer get to the start page, adding `["main_frame", "sub_frame", "script", "xmlhttprequest"]`.

What is still annoying is, if you reached your profile page and now click on start page (or the f-logo) nothing happens. It seams because this is an ajax call and my extension rewrites the url, no "new" page is loaded and we are stuck.

What can I do to get redirected back to facebook.com/messages even if its an ajax call or something else?

My background.js looks *now* like this:

```
var patternURL = new RegExp("http(s)?://www\.facebook\.com(/|/\\?ref=[^\/]*)?$");
var targetURL = "https://www.facebook.com/messages";
var patternShowIcon = new RegExp("http(s)?://www\.facebook\.com");

chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(function(details) {

    if (patternURL.test(details.url)) {
        return {
            redirectUrl : targetURL
        };
    }
}, {
    urls : ["*://*.facebook.com/*"],
    types : ["main_frame", "sub_frame", "script", "xmlhttprequest"]
}, ["blocking"]);

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {

    chrome.tabs.get(tabId, function(tab) {
        if (patternShowIcon.test(tab.url)) {
            chrome.pageAction.show(tabId);
        } else {
            chrome.pageAction.hide(tabId);
        }
    });
});
```

The whole source code as a link to the extension is available on [github](https://github.com/lony/facebook-hopper).

Comment: I believe the problem is in `main_frame`. Try other request types; if it helps, I'll make that into an answer.

Comment: So far so good ["main_frame", "sub_frame", "script", "xmlhttprequest"] seems to do the trick. One little problem still, if I catch AJAX request the page is not redirected and just stays on what ever page it is. Any ideas to solving this problem?

Comment: Include a description of the behavior you are intending for all this in the question.

Comment: I want if someone wants to visit his start page being automatically redirected to messages. At the moment he is just stuck at for example his profile page and can not go back to messages ones there.

Comment: Edit your question with that, I meant.

Comment: I suppose the answer may require deeper investigation of how FB navigates a user between its pages. But basically, you probably need to embed a content script into FB pages. Then, when onBeforeRequest is trapped, use messaging to send new url to the content script and instruct it to initiate redirection of the hosting page, not in the context of ajax request.